# Returning undistorted pixel coordinates rather than the image

Tags: python, image, opencv, matrix, distortion

I need to undistort the pixel coordinates of an image -- and need the corrected coordinates returned. I do not want an undistorted image returned-- just the corrected coordinates of the pixels. The camera is calibrated, and I have the camera intrinsic parameters, and the distortion matrix. I am using OpenCV in python 3

I have read up as much of the theory as I can find and questions here. Key info is:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html

This pretty clearly describes the radial distortion and tangential distortion that needs to be considered.
radial:

x_{corrected} = x( 1 + k_1 r^2 + k_2 r^4 + k_3 r^6)
y_{corrected} = y( 1 + k_1 r^2 + k_2 r^4 + k_3 r^6)

Tangential:

x_{corrected} = x + [ 2p_1xy + p_2(r^2+2x^2)]
y_{corrected} = y + [ p_1(r^2+ 2y^2)+ 2p_2xy]

I suspect that I can't simply apply these corrections sequentially. Perhaps there is a function to do what I want to do directly, anyway -- and I'd love to hear about that.

I can't simply use the normal undistort procedure on the image, as I am attempting to apply an IR camera's distortion correction to the depth data from the same camera. If you undistort a depth image like this -- you split pixels across coordinates and the answer makes no sense. Hopefully I am on the right track with this.

The code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
imgIR = cv2.imread("/20190529-150017-305-1235-depth.png",0)
#you could try this on any image...

h,  w = imgIR.shape[:2]

X = np.array([i for i in range(0,w)]*(h))
X = X.reshape(h, w)

Y = np.array([[i]*(w) for i in range(0,h)])

fx =    483.0 #x focal length
fy =    490.2
CentreX = 361.4 #optical centre of the image - x axis
CentreY = 275.6

#Relative to the optical centre, it is possible to determine the `#coordinates of each pixel in the image` 
#then do the above operation without loops using a scalar subtraction
Xref = X - CentreX
Yref = Y - CentreY

#"scaling factor" refers to the relation between depth units and meters;
scalingFactor = 18.0/36.0 # 18pixels / 36 mm;
# I'm not sure what should be yet -- whether [pixels at the shelf]/mm
#or mm/[pixels at the shelf]

Z = imgIR / scalingFactor


#using numpy
Xcoord = np.multiply(Xref,Z/fx)
Ycoord = np.multiply(Yref,Z/fy)

#how to correct these coords for the radial and tangential distortion?
#parameters as returned for the distortion matrix using 
cv2.calibrateCamera
dstvec = array([[-0.1225, -0.0159, 0.001616, -0.0018924,-0.00120696]])
```

What I am looking for is a new matrix of undistorted (radial and tangential distortion removed) X coordinates and a matrix of undistored Y coordinates -- with each matrix element representing one of the original pixels.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wonder if I can use

Comment: I wonder if I can use the following approach: Xnew, Ynew = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx,dstvec,None, newcameramtx, (w,h),5) where mtx and newcameramtx are the camera matrix and optimsed camera matrix?

Comment: fro. my undersranding, the map is exactly what you want

Comment: Thanks Micka -- I'm just giving it a shot. Might be answering my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for OpenCV's undistortPoints (https://amroamroamro.github.io/mexopencv/matlab/cv.undistortPoints.html).

```
px_distorted = np.zeros((1, 1, 2), dtype=np.float32)
px_distorted[0][0][0] = x_coordinate
px_distorted[0][0][1] = y_coordinate
px_undistorted = cv2.undistortPoints(px_distorted, intrinsics_mat, dist_coefficients)
```